# A contradiction that a number $g$ is a generator of a cyclic group

Tags: number-theory

For a prime number $p$ and a natural number $i$, let $q = p^{i}$. The $(Z^{*}_{q}, \cdot_{\text{ mod } q})$ is a cyclic group and let $g$ be its generator.

$$Z^{*}_{q} = \{ d \in Z_q \mid GCD(d,q) = 1 \}$$

We know that for a number $a$, $a \equiv g (\text{ mod } q)$.

It has been claimed that if $p \mid a$ then the equality

$g = a \text{ mod } p^i$

Contradicts the assumption that $g$ is a generator of $Z^{*}_{q}$

I would like to know why is this true?

Thanks

Comment: What are elements of $Z_q^*$?

Comment: Numbers $d$  from $1$ to $q-1$ where GCD$(d, q) =1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a \equiv g \mod p^i$ implies $a = g+kp^i$ for some integer $k$. Then $p \mid a$ implies $p \mid g$ since $p \mid (a-g)$. This contradicts $\gcd(g,p^i)=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. The last statement gcd(g,q)=1 is because generator of every group must be one of the elements of that group, right?